# TypeScript folder is missing when launching app

Tags: typescript, web, localhost

I have a problem when I want to test a website. When I launch my app in Visual Studio 2022, it compiles my Typescript files correctly but it's like my site waited for the TS files and didn't find it.

[Problem in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKf0U.png)

As you can see on the picture, the TSScripts folder seems to be in a bad state and it seems to be the problem.

I imagine it could be due to an error or a lack in my tsconfig.json.
here is it's content :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES6",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js",
    "module": "ES6",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "TSScripts/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Thank you.

Philippe

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what framework you're using, but TS files are not valid files to run in the browser. You need to compile your TS files into .js files before your browser can understand it. `tsc` does this beautifully and the output folder can be set using the `outDir` option in `tsconfig.json`. You would then point your HTML to include that folder.

Comment: I don't use any framework for the moment. I'm testing TS especially to use classes. I don't want to run the TS files, but when I want to add a breakpoint in my JS file compiled from TS, the browser (tested on Brave and Firefox) directly gives the error message. I don't understand why the browser points on the TS files.

Comment: Breakpoints are an IDE (not browser) feature. You most likely had to start debug mode on it, which handles the breakpoints. If you get your browser to load up your site without your IDE, the breakpoints don't work. There's essentially a websocket connection that tells your browser which file is triggering the breakpoint and the browser displays that. You can test this by adding `throw new Error()` in one of your files, building to JS, then running your site in your browser without your IDE. You will most likely see an error pointing to .js

Comment: My problem was solved by moving my TS scripts from the root of the project to the "wwwroot" folder. I don't know if it's a good thing but for the moment, I can go further with that.
Thank you.