# Can't Import node_modules

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, npm-install, primevue

I try to work with VueJs and PrimeVue in an existing Asp.Net Core project but I can't import the module. I guess my problem comes from the configuration of my project but I don't know how to solve it.

My project is an asp.net core project created in VS 2022. I installed npm with no particular option. After that, I installed PrimeVue and PimeIcons as it's shown on their site, that is : 
`npm install primevue@^3.17.0 --save` 
`npm install primeicons --save`

So my app tree is like this :

```
Project root folder
│   appsettings.Development.json
│   appsettings.json
│   ERP.csproj
│   package-lock.json
│   package.json
│   Program.cs
│   tsconfig.json
│       
├───node_modules
│   │   .package-lock.json   
│   ├───estree-walker        
│   ├───jquery               
│   ├───magic-string
│   ├───nanoid
│   ├───picocolors       
│   ├───postcss
│   ├───primeicons
│   ├───primevue
│   ├───source-map
│   ├───source-map-js
│   ├───sourcemap-codec
│   └───vue
├───obj
├───Properties
├───Views
└───wwwroot
    │   favicon.ico
    ├───css
    ├───js
    ├───lib   
    └───TSScripts
```

Then I make the import as their site says : 
`import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';` 
`import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';`

But when I launch the app from VS, I have this error : 
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "primevue/config". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

so I tried :
`import PrimeVue from './primevue/config';` 
`import './primeicons/primeicons.css';`

result : 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  :7080/js/Partenaires/primevue/config:1` 
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () :7080/js/Partenaires/primeicons/primeicons.css:1`

It seems that the files should be in the wwwroot folder instead of the root/node_modules folder.

I had a similar problem with my TypeScript files, there were in a folder in the root and the app didn't find them. I had to move the folder in the wwwroot folder to solve it without being sure it's the good way to do (see : [TypeScript folder is missing when launching app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717966/typescript-folder-is-missing-when-launching-app))

Can someone explain me what should I do to solve this problem ?

Thank you.

Philippe

Answer (score 1):

Didn't saw your project structure before.
Make sure, that you use vite to create your project. Follow the guide at https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project.

It would honestly be easier to just create a new project instead of finding the issue with your current setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as I'm in testing phase yet, I can take time to try something different.